# Backbone - cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

This is my first time really trying to create a Backbone application with a server endpoint and I have found myself in a bit of a snag.

I have an underscore template in my html here:

```
    <tbody>
      <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
        <tr>
          <td><% user.get('firstname') %></td>
          <td><% user.get('lastname') %></td>
          <td><% user.get('age') %></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      <% }); %>
    </tbody>
```

And I here is my model/view/collection:

```
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/UMA.Service/Service1.svc/',
        Model: User
    });

var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "firstname": "",
        "lastname": "",
        "age": null
    }
});

var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
        var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users: this.collection.model});
        this.$el.html(template);

    }, 
    initialize: function() {    
        var that = this;        
        this.collection = new Users();
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(User) {
                that.render();
            }
        });

    }
});
```

I am not really sure where I am messing up. I thought that it might have to be how I am calling something in my collection or model but I have looked for a while and cannot find it if there is. Would anyone be able to help me out?

I have my console log in my render function in the view and that returns all of my data so I cannot see why this is not working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: With `{users: this.collection.model}` you're setting `users` to the `User` class. Your `_.each` iterates over the methods/properties of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
_.each(users, function(user) {...
```

Try doing:

```
users.each(function(user) { ...
```

Backbone "proxys" various underscore methods onto backbone objects (in this case the Collection object). For more info check this out: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods and scroll down a little to a few of the examples.

Edit:

@Bojangels is right. You also don't want to pass this.collection.model into the template. You just want to pass the collection through (in this case). The collection "contains" the models you care about. Collection.model is an attribute on the collection that says what type of model the collection contains, not a specific instance of the model itself.

As @Tallmaris stated in the comment bellow, the missing piece of the puzzle was to use `<%=` to putput the values:

```
  <td><%= user.get('firstname') %></td>
```

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem of passing `this.collection.model` to the template. I'll let you work out why that's wrong

Comment: @csjohn - Thanks for helping out. I was changed my underscore code as you had suggested. I also changed `this.collection.model` to `this.collection`. I am still not getting the data to show up. However, the error is gone. Now i just have a bunch of blank rows with no more errors though. I checed the JSON response in my Network tab and it shows all of the data in there. it just isnt printing to the scree. any ideas?

Comment: Yep, use `<%=` to output values. `<%` is for evaluation. @csjohn you may want to add it to your answer

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the collection to the template correctly.  You need to do this.collection.toJSON()
Your render function should look like this

```
render: function() {
        console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
        var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users: this.collection.toJSON()});
        this.$el.html(template);

}
```